# Can't Debug WCF Service

Tags: wcf, debugging, wcf-data-services

I have two WCF services in a single solution (let's call it the service solution).  I've deployed those services on a remote machine.  I have another solution in which I consume those services by creating a reference to the services on the remote machine (let's call it the client solution).  The code for both services is up to date on the remote machine (AFAIK), because I have deployed the most up to date code to it.

The issue is that in the service solution I can debug one of the services but not the other.  The one that fails gives this error when I put a breakpoint on it.

**The breakpoint will not currently be hit.  The source code is different from the original version.**

The question is, what could be different between the two WCF services to allow one to be debuggable and the other not.

Comment: Are you using remote debugging?

Comment: no both solutions are on my local machine as is the code.

Comment: If you have referenced the services on a remote machine, and you are attaching (I assume) to a local W3P process, I would not expect any of the breakpoints to be hit. I may be wrong as I have never tried it this way and would usually host the service locally and then attach the debugger to that process and step through the code. Is this something I am not aware of?

Comment: Well both of the services are remote and debugging works fine for one of them just not the other one.

Comment: That is what I can't understand. Neither should work as far as I know. Are you 100% sure both references are to the remote machine? If you run the operations on the client, does the working breakpoint actually get hit? It could be that your local W3P process has a cache of one of the services and not the other and it is just giving the impression that one is working and not the other, when in fact, they both won't. Curious...